# What does the sentence “wear your sleeve on your heart” mean?

Tags: slang

“There are difficulties and the possibility of heartbreak. There always are in high school. You wear your sleeve on your heart. There are parents.”

Is it same like the sentence of “wear your heart on your sleeve”?

Comment: It's most likely an intentional reversal of the stock phrase, so I would interpret it to mean the exact opposite -- you wear your sleeve on your heart so that your heart is not exposed.

Comment: I googled it. And i find that the majority of people use “wear your sleeve on your heart” instead of the intentional one. Does it mean it isn’t a common usage?

Comment: 6300 hits for "wear your sleeve on your heart", 560,000 hits for "wear your heart on your sleeve".  And apparently "wear your sleeve on your heart" has some connection to a piece of music and to tattoos.

Comment: And the piece you quote is from a movie review by Roger Ebert.  He would have been totally aware of the "correct" phrase and thus almost certainly intended it as an ironic reversal in meaning -- ie, hide your feelings.

Comment: @Hot Licks -  the actual Google figures are "wear your sleeve on your heart" 41; "wear your heart on your sleeve " 224. The hugely optimistic number given by Google in the first line never bears any relation to the real figure. The trick is to click to the end of the Google page list until the search results end. You will then be presented with: "*In order to show you the most relevant results, we have omitted some entries very similar to the 41 already displayed*."

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simple malapropism, or misstatement of the phrase you mentioned:

> wear your heart on your sleeve.

Metaphorically this just means making your inner thoughts (your heart) more public (visibly external).

The other direction makes no sense metaphorically or literally.

Comment: It does metaphorically. As @Hot Licks comments, it could mean keep your heart concealed behind your sleeve. In others words the exact opposite of wearing your heart on your sleeve. However, I believe any occurrences are either deliberate jokes or simple errors.